# How to use Selective Bayesian Forest Classifier (SBFC) in R?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-network

I came across with this r package 'sbfc'. It appears very interesting as they talk about Bayesian Forest and it competes with random forest performance. If someone can walk me through this package with examples and explanation that would be very helpful to the community including me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the paper on it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02371.pdf. If I understood correctly, it's supposed to be an improvement over Naive Bayes. They tested it alongside other Bayes models using MCMC. Their results show that on average, it outperformed them.

> It builds parsimonious
>   yet flexible models using tree-structured Bayesian
>   networks, and samples an ensemble of such models using
>   Markov chain Monte Carlo. We build in feature selection
>   by dividing the trees into two groups according to their relevance
>   to the outcome of interest. Our method performs
>   competitively on classification and feature selection benchmarks
>   in low and high dimensions, and includes a visualization
>   tool that provides insight into relevant features and
>   interactions.

Comment: Please provide a summary of the paper. – *Reviewer*

Comment: They don’t claim it outperformed the competing methods (it did not beat BART for example). They only say it was competitive, which honestly is the most anyone should ever say with these benchmark datasets that have been beaten to death.